Paired t-test of two algorithms
I want to compare the speed of two algorithms. However I'm having troubles interpreting the results. Is my approach correct?
Null hypothesis: The algorithms have same speed
Alternative hypothesis: Algorithm Y is faster.
my data:
algorithm_x = np.array(
    [1014, 1007, 998, 1040, 999, 1030, 980, 1010, 940, 1030, 1000, 990, 1000, 995, 1020, 990, 1040, 1020, 1015, 940])
algorithm_y = np.array(
    [980, 995, 960, 1050, 970, 1010, 1005, 1020, 950, 1000, 1025, 970, 965, 980, 1015, 985, 1010, 995, 990, 955])

using scipy I calculated the p-value:
pvalue = scipy.stats.ttest_rel(algorithm_x, algorithm_y, alternative="greater").pvalue

and I got the result: $pvalue = 0.011638$
I was thinking the following:
Because the pvalue is less than our confidence interval 95% (0.05) we reject null hypothesis, thus the alternative hypothesis is true. So algorithm Y is indeed faster than algorithm X.
Is my thinking correct?

Your formulation should be corrected, but your conclusion may be okay, although ...
It is wrong to say that "the p value is less than the confidence interval". Change it into: "The p value is less than the chosen value of $\alpha$ (0.05)".
It is wrong to say that Y is indeed faster than X. It's better to say: "The test result supports the alternative hypothesis that Y is faster than X". Statistical tests only can make an idea more plausible, but never proof it.
Finally: are you sure you can test one-sided? Is there a good reason why Y could not be slower than X, on the average? Looking at your data, Y sometimes is slower, so I would suggest to test two-sided.
